# It there a way to automatically create list views based off of a new item in a separate list?

Tags: list, list-view, view, sharepoint-views

List "A" is a list of Employee Profiles. List "B" is a list of Documents their supervisors have completed.

Is there a way to get sharepoint to automatically create a listview when a new profile in list "A" is created?

Example. Profile for John Doe is created in List "A". Then listview "John Doe" is auto created for list "B" which show only Documents with John Doe's name attached.

I want to be able to automatically add a link to this listview in new items in List "A".

Comment: Instead of creating a listview, can you connect ListA with ListB with the Title column? This would give a filtered view of documents in ListB. So when the record in ListA is selected, the ListB would refresh to show only documents related to that record only.

Comment: @AhmadZia Do you mind going into more detail? I am not sure how to connect lists in the way you are describing.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are two lists ListA and ListB on a page. These two lists web parts can be connected with one field. Please see below. ListA Title column is connected to ListB Title column. So when a new employee is created in ListA, it would have a connection in ListB provided the ListB has a corresponding supervisor.

So basically you need to maintain data in two lists and there is no need to create a separate list view for each employee.

[image]

You can edit the page and then edit ListA web part to connect to ListB as below.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is not the vision that upper management had for this process, but it might actually work out better! I will be work on it with my counterpart and keep you updated